# How to get all transaction_email ,transaction status from sql query Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, sql, transaction

I am trying to get all 
`transactions`,`transactions_id`,`transaction_email`,`transaction status`  by SQL query.
I found the table where all transactions are stored `sales_payment_transaction`, `sales_order_payment` and `sales_order`

So I can easily get all `transactions` and 'transactions_id'
but how can I get `transaction_email`,`transaction status`

> SQL query

```
SELECT spt.transaction_id, spt.txn_id, spt.is_closed, so.customer_email
FROM sales_payment_transaction spt 
INNER JOIN sales_order so on spt.order_id = so.entity_id;
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, by `transaction_email` you meant customer email and by `transaction status` you meant a way to identify whether order was placed successfully or not.

Customer email is present in `sales_order` table.

Generally when you click the "Place Order" button, order status is `pending` and when you make the payment successfully, order status changes to `processing`. You can get order status from `sales_order` table.

Here is the sql query for the same:

```
SELECT spt.order_id, 
    spt.transaction_id,
    spt.txn_id,
    so.customer_email,
    so.status
FROM sales_payment_transaction spt 
JOIN sales_order so ON spt.order_id = so.entity_id
```